# How to use python statement as SELECT condition in SQLite?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

Normally, we can use only SQL statements as SELECT condition (using WHERE clause). However, it is sometimes useful to use python (or any language which evoke SQL) statement as SELECT condition.

For example, there is a example [in the document of sqlite3 module of python](http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html#converting-sqlite-values-to-custom-python-types), where a structure `Point` was stored into a table. However it is hard to query the table using the structure `Point`. Say, I want to do `SELECT p FROM table WHERE P.x=4` which select all the point with x coordinate equal to 4. But that `SELECT` statement won't work since `P.x` is a python statement rather than a SQL statement.

Another example of this is that when the SELECT condition is too complex for SQL language. Say, I want to SELECT all integers which mod 4 is 3 or things like this.

So, is there any idea of doing this? Thank you!

EDIT: In respect of zam664's answer, it is surely possible for the first example to use P_X and P_Y. However, what if p is a list of an unknown length (which is able to be stored in a table using adapters) and I want to `SELECT p FROM table WHERE 2 in p`. I think this is a useful case.

Comment: Just a note; since the database won't execute Python but SQL only (ie the Python query would need to be automatically translated to SQL), any queries too complex to express in SQL would still be too complex if you wrote them in Python. The only thing Python could possibly help you with regarding complexity is automatically doing part of the query in the database and part once in code once you get the result back.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to split the load between SQL and python code.  You would need to structure the data in your tables properly so that SQL could get most of if and then record check the rest for the complicated stuff.

You should be able to get most of it in SQLite so that a SQL query would work.  You would just need to brek up your data.  For example your point with x and y fields would need to be split upon in SQLite to 2 fields like P_X and P_Y.

SQLite is a relational DBMS not an object DBMS.  If you need an object DBMS then SQLite is the wrong product for the task.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, there are some cases where this splitting data method may failed. See the EDIT for details.

Answer (score 0):

Since the data is stored as a ; separated string list, you should be able to do something like:

```
SELECT point FROM test WHERE point LIKE '%x=4%
```

With reservation for using incorrect table and column names.